# Syntax for reading csv file and changing to character

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file and am reading it in to my program.  Can someone explain why

```
kfreq1=as.character(read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=","))
```

produces the output

```
[1] "c(35, 116, 103, 43, 76, 94, 102, 11, 108, 106, 80, 84, 1, 107, 21, 46, 50, 31, 19, 39, 30, 92, 88, 36, 22, 118, 38, 101, 12, 63, 60, 33, 91, 112, 9, 105, 52, 41, 18, 66, 56, 7, 69, 89, 74, 96, 3, 53, 57, 71, 100, 29, 113, 111, 58, 104, 62, 25, 59, 40, 83, 44, 110, 61, 68, 65, 67, 51, 85, 28, 13, 75, 17, 42, 115, 6, 8, 15, 78, 55, 73, 114, 47, 90, 34, 82, 95, 72, 97, 70, 4, 86, 117, 119, 45, 109, 26, 20, 81, 27, 2, 48, 98, 54, 64, 49, 87, 79, 120, 99, 10, 24, 23, 5, 37, 93, 14, 77, 32, 16)"
[2] "c(7, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)"
```

yet

```
kfreq1=as.character(read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")$V1)
```

produces the output

```
[1] "environmental"     "using"             "software"          "experience"        "policy"           
[6] "research"          "skills"            "candidate"         "support"           "statistical"
...
```

For reference the file is formatted like this

```
environmental,7
using,5
software,4
```

Comment: If you need to convert the columns to character class. You can specifyin the read.csv with `colClasses` or after reading it i.e. `df1 <- read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=","); df1$v1 <- as.character(df1$v1)`

Comment: What is the easiest way to read the file and capitalize the words in the first column?

Comment: Try `toupper(df1$v1)`  `as.character` works on `vectors`

Comment: But I also need to keep the second column.  So basically I want the data read to go from this

environmental,7
using,5
software,4

to this

ENVIRONMENTAL,7
USING,5
SOFTWARE,4

Comment: Just assign `df1$v1 <- toupper(df1$v1)`

Answer (score 3):

We can read the data using `read.csv` as in the OP's code.

```
  df1 <- read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE, sep=",")
```

If we need to convert a column to 'character' class, using `colClasses` argument in `read.csv` is one option, which would also be useful if there are other `class` e.g. 'Date'.  Another way is by specifying `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in `read.csv/read.table`.  The default method is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`, so any non-numeric column will be transformed to `factor` class by not specifying the `stringsAsFactors` argument in `read.csv/read.table`.

Suppose if we need to convert a single `factor` column to `character` class, we extract the column with `df1$V1` or `df1[,'V1']` or `df1[['V1']]` or the numeric index of the column `df1[,1]` and wrap with `as.numeric` (In this example, we only have a single `factor` column).

```
 df1$V1 <- as.character(df1$V1)
```

If we need to convert all the `factor` columns to `character` (in general), we can loop using `lapply` on all the `factor` columns (`df1[indx]`) in the dataset.

```
 indx <- sapply(df1, is.factor)#create a logical index of 'factor' columns
 df1[indx] <- lapply(df1[indx], as.character)
```

---

Regarding the second part of the question about capitalizing the words in 'V1' column, we can use the function `toupper`

```
 df1$V1 <- toupper(df1$V1)
 df1$V1
 #[1] "ENVIRONMENTAL" "USING"         "SOFTWARE"
```

NOTE: This also works with `factor` class, but the output will be `character` class.

Comment: Great I'll try all of this out.